# Using HQL to select from joined tables having one to many relationship between them

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I am stuck with this Hibernate thing and dont know how to figure it out. Please help !

So I have these two tables:

```
POSITION
positionid(PK), description

JOB
jobid(PK),positionid(FK),description
```

How do I use HQL in Hibernate to fetch all jobs with their corresponding position descriptions ?

Edit: So this what I am trying to achieve:

```
JOBID     POSITION.DESCRPTION     JOB.DESCRIPTION
  1        Teacher                Science Teacher
  2        Coach                  Football Coach
```

and so on for all job's in JOB table. I am trying to figure out what will be HQL for this.

I have put together the following code till now :

position.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.XXXX.model.Position" table="POSITION">
   <id name="positionID" type="int" column="POSITIONID" >
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>

  <property name="description">
   <column name="DESCRIPTION" />
  </property>

  <set name="jobs">
    <key column="positionID" />
    <one-to-many class="com.XXXX.model.Job" />
  </set>

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

job.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>

  <class name="com.XXXX.model.Job" table="JOB">
   <id name="jobID" type="int" column="JOBID" >
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>

  <property name="description">
   <column name="DESCRIPTION" />
  </property>

  <many-to-one name="position" class="com.XXXX.model.Position" column="positionID" />

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Position.java

```
public class Position {

    private int positionID;
    private String description;
    private Set<Job> jobs = new HashSet<Job>();

    // Getters and Setters for all the above three follows...

}
```

Job.java

```
public class Job {

    private int jobID;
    private String description;
    private Position position;

    // Getters and Setters for all the above three follows...
}
```

In my code now I use

```
session.createQuery("from Position as p left join p.positionID as pid").list();
```

I know its not exactly correct and I am getting the follow error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3268)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3060)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2938)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
    .........................
    ...........................
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this please ?

Comment: A join is used to navigate through an association between two entities. Your query makes no sense. What do you really want to achieve? You say that yuou want all the jobs with their position description, but your code shows that you want to get a `List<Position>`.

Comment: Hi I understand the confusion, I was trying out with the query I have quoted above, not even sure that's correct. I have now updated the question with what I am really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want these three columns, then the HQL should be

```
select job.id, position.decription, job.description 
from Job job
left join job.position position
```

This query will return a `List<Object[]>` and each Object array in the list will contain these three elements.

It would be much more natural however to use this query:

```
select job from Job job
left join fetch job.position
```

which would load all the jobs with their position. The query would return a List, and you would be able to access the three information uou want using `job.getId()`, `job.getPosition().getDescription()`, and `job.getDescription()`.

The syntax of HQL is described with examples in the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql), a must-read.

Comment: Thanks, this worked liked a charm, I will go with the second query as it will be helpful if add more columns and of course, I feel its the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just getJobs() from the Position object